# Synthetic construction of rational normal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

We consider the so called '*Synthetic or Steiner construction*', which
can be found e.g. in [this script](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/287y.pdf) or Joe Harris' *Algebraic Geometry*
on page 14 which should finally be recognized as rational normal curve. (we work always over $\mathbb{C}$)

The *synthetic construction* works as follows: Let say we have $\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n} $ codimension two subspaces in
$\mathbb{P}^{n} $. (are they realy allowed to be arbitrary?) Let for every $i =1,...,n$ be $\{H_{\lambda}^i \}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}}$
the pencil of hyperplanes containing the plane $\Lambda_i$
with *additional assumption* that for every $t_0 \in \mathbb{P}^{1}$ the planes
$H_{\lambda}^1,...H_{\lambda}^n$ are independent, i.e., intersect in a unique  point $p(\lambda)$.

Consider the union of
intersections of these hyperplanes:

$$ C:= \bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_{\lambda}^1 \cap ... \cap H_{\lambda}^n $$

In the linked script is is claimed that this curve
is a *rational normal curve*, i.e. projectively equivalent
to the curve obtained as image of the Veronese map

$$ v_d: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^n,
[X_0:X_1] \mapsto [X_0^n: X_0^{n-1}X_1:..., X_1^n]$$

In  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170453/steiner-construction-of-rational-normal-curve) I wanted to discuss how generally to prove that the Steiner construction
above gives indeed a rational normal curve. One almost fruitful approach was to work with explicite parametrizations, ie
to realize the coefficients $r_{i, Z_j}$ of every linear equation

$$\lambda_0 L_{1,i} + \lambda_1 L_{i,2}
 = r_{i,Z_0} (\lambda)Z_0+ r_{i,Z_1} (\lambda)Z_1 + ... + r_{i, Z_d} (\lambda)Z_d =0$$

associated to hyperplane $H_{\lambda}^i$ as $i$-th row of a matrix
$R \in \operatorname{Mat}_{n+1}(K(\lambda))$, where the $(n+1)$-row is filled with zeroes.
Then by construction the $(n+1)$-column of
adjungate matrix $A= R^{\mathrm{adj}}$ to $R$ provides for varying $\lambda$ the parametrization $[A_0(\lambda):...:A_n(\lambda)]$ of my curve $C$. Indeed,
every entry in $A$ is homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $\lambda$.
The problem which remains unsolved using this strategy
is that it not shows $A_i(\lambda)$ are linearly independent. Since a rational normal curve is non-degenerated and non-degeneracy of the image of the constrcted map

$$\lambda \mapsto [A_0(\lambda):...:A_n(\lambda)]$$

is non-degenerated iff $A_i$ are linearly independent, this leads me to the motivation of *this* question treating this problem separately:

**Question**: Is it possible to show directly that this curve
$C= \bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_{\lambda}^1 \cap ... \cap H_{\lambda}^n \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
constructed above is *non-degenerated*, ie is not contained in a
hyperplane $\mathbb{P}^{n-1} \cong H \subset \mathbb{P}^n$?

Preferably, is there a *synthetic* way using intersection theoretical methods
to show non-degeneracity of $C$? Under *'synthetic'* or coordinate free I mean that I want to
know if it is possible to derive the non-degeneracity of $C$ only by
'playing' with the synthetic construction of $C$ from above by analyzing it's intersections with appropriate hyperperplanes, so using 'synthetic' arguments, instead of constructing concrete parametrizations as sketched above in my 'almost proof'.
More precisely I hoped to argue via contraposition, that is to *assume* that $C$ is contained in a hyperplane, and then obtain somehow something total absurd on intersection behavior. Does anybody see how it can be realized?

Can moreover with similar methods verified directly that $C$ has degree $d$?