# Varieties swept out by Linear Spaces nondegenerated

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

We working over complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ keeping our constructions
as geometric as possible.
Let  $\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_m \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n} $ be pairwise distinct, codimension two linear subspaces in
$\mathbb{P}^{n} $ with $m \le n$.
Let for every $i =1,...,m$ be $\{H_{\lambda}^i \}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}}$
the pencils of hyperplanes containing the plane $\Lambda_i$
with *additional assumption (!)* that for *every* $\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}$ the planes
$H_{\lambda}^1,...H_{\lambda}^m$ are linearly independent,
i.e.

$$H_{\lambda}^1 \cap ... \cap H_{\lambda}^m \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-m}$$

Consider the union of
intersections of these hyperplanes:

$$ V_m:= \bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_{\lambda}^1 \cap ... \cap H_{\lambda}^m $$

How to prove that $V_m$ *non-degenerated*, that is not contained in a hyperplane
$\mathbb{P}^{n-1} \cong H \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ for $3 \le m \le n$
most 'geometrically /elementary/ old-school-like', e.g. by obtaining a contradiction on intersection countings
if we would assume $C$ were degenerated?
Case $m=2$ is quite easy (indeed, assuming $V_2 \subset H \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ would lead to $V_2= \Lambda_1 \cup \Lambda_2$, a contradiction, since $V_m$'s are irreducible) but I not see an argument now it can be naturally extended to $m \ge 3$.

Observe that's generalizes
[Synthetic construction of rational normal curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396298/synthetic-construction-of-rational-normal-curve)